# Tolerance: For the droppable's middle that is closest the draggable's middle?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

I have an item list using draggable and droppable. It's containing items you can move into droppable folders. You can also change order of items dragging n' dropping them in different order. But the precision is not good. So, non of the current tolerance options works like I want it to.

As the title says; I want the drop to be able for the droppable's middle that are closest to the draggable's middle. Which also means that only one drop area is possible at each drop. How do I make it possible?

Here is the droppable part of the code:

```
// Handle
            base.$el.find(base.options.handle).droppable(
            {
                  tolerance  : "intersect"
                , hoverClass : "tree_hover"
                , drop       : function(event, ui)
                {
                    //console.log(pos.target(), pos.section());
                    base.pos.targetX = ui.offset.left;
                    base.pos.targetY = $(this).offset().top;
                    base.pos.targetH = $(this).height();

                    $(this).removeClass('tree_hover');

                    var dropped = ui.draggable;
                    dropped.css({ top: 0, left: 0 });

                    var me = $(this).parent();

                        if (me == dropped)
                            return;

                    ui.draggable.addClass('moved');

                    var subbranch = me.children("ul");

                    switch (base.pos.target())
                    {
                        case 'on':

                            //add as a child
                            if (subbranch.size() == 0)
                            {
                                //add new ul
                                var newb = $('<ul></ul>');
                                newb.append(dropped);
                                me.append(newb);
                            } else {
                                subbranch.eq(0).append(dropped);
                            }

                            if (!me.hasClass('parent')) me.addClass('parent expanded');

                            break;

                        case 'above':

                            //add before
                            dropped.insertBefore(me);
                            break;

                        case 'below':

                            //add after
                            dropped.insertAfter(me);
                            break;  
                    }

                    me.removeClass('on above below');

                    //remove parent from items that no longer contain children
                    $('ul.tree li.parent ul').filter(function()
                    {
                        return $(this).children().length == 0;

                    }).closest('li').removeClass('parent').end().remove();

                    //callback
                    if (base.options.itemMoved != null)
                    {
                        base.options.itemMoved(base.getMoved());
                    }

                }, over: function(e, ui)
                {
                    base.pos.targetX = ui.offset.left;
                    base.pos.targetY = $(this).offset().top;
                    base.pos.targetH = $(this).height();

                }, out: function(e, ui)
                {
                    $(this).closest('li').removeClass('on above below');
                }
            });
```